# Change fixed div content/display at vertical points

Tags: javascript, html, transition

I'd like to create a vertical website with multiple div's that appear at certain y-points on a website. These div's will host text. The position of these div's will always be fixed. 20% from the left and about 250px from the top.

What I want is to have the content of the div to display at certain vertical points on the page and disappear when I scroll down to the next description; only to have the next div appear straight after that. So that they have a quick transition from a to b.

A few good examples are:

Clicking on the links of this site makes the descriptions appear and they change on scroll: http://www.mattssonvandeneeden.nl/
The type in the centre: http://www.freetoair.org.uk/
The headings: http://www.formsofinquiry.com/

Can anyone point me into a particular direction or help me work out how it's done. I've looked at their code and still cant get it to work.

Comment: We can help you in showing directions. But the actual coding you will have to do :)

Comment: Secondly, seen your profile, and you have asked 4 questions and hasn't accepted any answer. Please do if you get a correct answer. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `scrollTop()`, `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions to achieve this. Depending upon the scroll placing you will show/hide relevant divs.

You can check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dB7eF/) demo on jsFiddle.net.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you! Just a couple of questions though.

Is it possible to have it so no modifications need to be made to the javascript if you add more div's? And each javascript title is the same? And to be even more annoying (so sorry!) is it possible to have it so that it can automatically detect the height of the parent div? I'm interested in having divs of different heights and am worried that the more divs the messier the javascript. Someone broke down of of those sites here: http://jsfiddle.net/kRAzZ/2/

Comment: You can use `.height()` function of jQuery. But not sure will this work in your case. As of now I don't know any solution for this. You can explore jQuery, you might get some answers :)